# Graphics are very slow on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I realise there are many threads regarding this issue. Nonetheless I've tried different solutions unsuccessfully.

The problem :  The graphical performance is very slow, windows motion not fluid at all, typing relatively slower than when i'm using my host system (windows).

Here are my system specs using lshw

```
aetos-virtualbox          
description: Computer
product: VirtualBox ()
vendor: innotek GmbH
version: 1.2
serial: 0
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
configuration: family=Virtual Machine uuid=820C9F41-5397-418F-A18F-85ABA9EDAD7D
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: VirtualBox
   vendor: Oracle Corporation
   physical id: 0
   version: 1.2
   serial: 0
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: innotek GmbH
      physical id: 0
      version: VirtualBox
      date: 12/01/2006
      size: 128KiB
      capabilities: isa pci cdboot bootselect int9keyboard int10video acpi
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 1
      size: 7985MiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 2
      bus info: cpu@0
      width: 64 bits
      apabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni monitor ssse3 lahf_lm
*-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-ide
         description: IDE interface
         product: 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
         version: 01
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master
         configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=64
         resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:d000(size=16)
    *-display UNCLAIMED
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
         vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:e0000000-e7ffffff
```

And I did a test via Run Manager, the graphics tests result is this:

```
graphics/driver_version             PASSED
graphics/display                    PASSED
graphics/resolution                 PASSED
graphics/compiz_check               FAILED  Not software rendered: no Compiz supported: no
graphics/VESA_drivers_not_in_use    PASSED
graphics/minimum_resolution         PASSED
```

More information :

```
I allocated 128 Mo to graphical memory via Virtualbox configuration (before strating system).
I checked 3D acceleration option.
I installed Virtual box guest additions
No graphical proprietary drivers are being used
virtualbox version : 3.4.12
```

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox extension pack?

Comment: No, if you're talking about the one downloadable from the website. but I did run the update manager after I installed Ubuntu, but idk if it's related.

Comment: Not closely related no.  The extension pack is located at http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.12-93733.vbox-extpack

Comment: Here, I installed the extension pack, but nothing changed regarding teh graphical performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's the VirtualBox version that is at fault.
What worked for me : I uninstalled Virtualbox 4.3.12 and installed 4.3.6 as the problem remains in the later versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, this deflect in guest additions is popular. There are plenty of threads/tickets filled for the issue. Closed & reopened again because same version may work for some but not for others.

One related ticket: [#12941 3D not working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941).

What worked for me:

1. Upgraded VirtualBox to last stable release 4.3.12-93733 from:

   ```
   deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
   ```
2. Upgraded installed guest additions in Guest Ubuntu to 4.3.12-93733 that comes with it.

Well, if it didn't work, I suggest trying one of the last test case Guest additions (mentioned in linked ticket):

- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-94438.iso
- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-94159.iso

If still the same, try downgrade VirtualBox to older release.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing common grapics driver package:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all
```

Comment: xserver-xorg-video-all is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and not upgraded.